# How to change partition RAID Member

Tags: partitioning, raid, mdadm

I would like to change the partition of my HD, an exception is thrown when I try to change or delete the whole disk volume. See the image of my HDD below:

- My actual setup. I would like to delete `/dev/sda1`.

  [image]
- The error:

  [image]

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]!  **;-)** What are you trying to accomplish?  Use the disks separately instead of in a RAID config???

Comment: Hi Fabby, how are you? So I had a raid on another machine running. this error hd is what was part of a raid array. I would like to clean it and redo a new raid configuration on this machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove mdadm raid1 without loosing data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/684453/remove-mdadm-raid1-without-loosing-data)

Comment: I think not Fabby, my problem is not with the md0 array but in not being able to delete the disk /dev/sda1

Comment: You need to break the array before you can do anything with the disk...  Try out the duplicate first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as Fabby said, you have to stop the array before making any changes. I did not have that in mind, thank you Fabby.

Here is the solution step by step:

`# mdadm -S /dev/md0`

`# mdadm /dev/md0 -r /dev/sda`

`# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M count=1024`

[after changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3NVe.png)

`# rm /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`