# Dual boot Ubuntu with Windows: cannot change from RAID to AHCI through BIOS

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, raid, ahci

I recently got a new laptop HP Envy (Model: 15M-ED0023DX). Its full SSD machine and I want to the change the SATA from RAID to AHCI so that I could see the partitions when I boot from pendrive (Ubuntu) [Reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152305/how-to-change-partition-raid-member).

However when I go to BIOS I do not see AHCI as an option. A similar answer from HP Forum [Reference](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/How-can-I-change-SATA-bios-of-HP-Envy-from-RAID-RST-to-AHCI/m-p/7677062/Pop_SU#M593684).

Is there any way around this, so that I can install Ubuntu on my machine?

Thanks

Comment: have you updated UEFI from HP? Perhaps this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134503/cant-boot-ubuntu-because-windows-10-rewrites-entire-efi-partition-solved

Comment: @oldfred Thank you. I disabled the Optane memory and it worked.! thanks!

Comment: Was that a separate setting from AHCI? I do not have Optane so do not know details.

Comment: I just disabled Optane from BIOS, and suddenly the partitions showed up. But due to it my windows crashed completely, and couldn't even read anything on the disk. I had to reinstall it. But I guess if we disable Optane from the Intel Software in windows first (before changing in BIOS), this issue is not observed. After reinstalling windows works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After disabling Optane from Intel's RAID software, as we as from BIOS, all the partitions are visible when you live boot, so its safe install.

Please Note: Windows might crash when you disable optane, so keep a windows bootable ready too, if you need to reinstall it.