# Having trouble to dual boot ubuntu on HP Pavilion along with windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, windows, hp, rst

When I tried to boot Ubuntu from a USB  it says that my PC doesn't have RST. I don't know what that means and everything I read online isn't helping at all.

Kindly advise on what to do. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What model HP? What video card/chip? Old BIOS or newer UEFI? If HP installed Windows 10 then it is UEFI.  Have you updated UEFI firmware to latest available. Many HP users find that resolves issues. Also SSD firmware update if SSD. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Shows Windows screens
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi HP with optane
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257230/dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-cannot-change-from-raid-to-ahci-through-bios?noredirect=1#comment2125560_1257230

Comment: RST stands for Rapid Storage Technology.
https://www.jihosoft.com/windows-tips/intel-rst-is-not-running.html
Do you have any SATA disk in your pc?