# How can I create mdadm RAID1 without losing data?

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have a 4TB hard drive. I mounted that hard drive in `/var`, to be able to store and make backups of a production server, and I came up with the idea of creating a RAID 1. For that I requested another 4TB hard drive although not the same make and model, but I think it will work...

I would like to create a RAID 1 without losing data already stored.
But the information I have found is not as complete as one would like...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fast view of what we are going to do:**

1. If new disk hasn't partition created, create partition
2. Stop all process that are using `/var`
3. Remove `/var` from `/etc/fstab`, to stop mount at start server
4. Restart server
5. Create RAID 1(`md0`) in new disk/partition(`/dev/sdc1`), and format the new partition(`/dev/md0`) with ext4
6. Clone information from old partition(`/dev/sdb1`) to new partition(`/dev/md0`)
7. Then add old partition(`/dev/sdb1`) to RAID 1(`md0`)
8. Add RAID 1(`md0`) to `/etc/fstab` to mount at start server
9. Restart

### Step by step

> **Note**: **Original disk:** `/dev/sdb` **partition** `/dev/sdb1`, **New disk:** `/dev/sdc`

**Create a new partition in new disk:**
If you hasn't create a partition in new disk use `gdisk` since `fdisk` can not do a partition larger than 2TB, after create new partition(`/dev/sdc1`) you can check with `lsblk`

```
gdisk /dev/sdc
# Type letter n
# Then enter
# Then enter
# Then enter
# Then enter
# Type letter w to write GPT data...
```

**Format(`ext4`) the new partition(`/dev/sdc1`) with `mkfs.ext4`**
We need to format the new partition to mount RAID 1 in it, you can check the new format in the partition(`/dev/sdc1`) with `lsblk`

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc1
```

**Remove `/dev/sdb1` from mount at start server to stop using files**
We want to copy all files from old disk/partition(`/dev/sdb1`) to new disk/partition(`/dev/md0` that is under `sdc1`), so first, we need to free files from process, we need to remove `/dev/sdb1` from mount at `/var`, you can't `umount /dev/sdb1` because Linux and others process use some files in `/var`.

```
nano /etc/fstab
# comment the line with # at start of the line like this:
# #UUID=24f081e2-fe9d-4ec1-81a6-c5c2d71d6c9b      /var    ext4    defaults        0       2
# to prevent /dev/sdb1 mount at /var
```

**Restart server**
We need to reboot to take effect...

```
reboot now
```

**Adding new disk/partition to RAID 1**
We need to add the new partition(`/dev/sdc1`) to mdadm to create RAID 1, format it with `ext4`

```
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --force --level=1 --raid-devices=1 /dev/sdc1
# type y to continue

# after create md0, we need to format with ext4
mkfs.ext4 /dev/md0

# use lsblk -f to check partitions and FSTYPE
```

**Copy data from old disk/partition to new disk/partition**
We need to copy old data from old partition `/dev/sdb1` to new partition `/dev/md0`, first create two folders to mount the two partitions and then clone data with `rsync` or `cp`...

```
cd /mnt
# go to path /mnt, I prefer this path because we are going to mount(mnt), you can create it wherever you want, and mount it

mkdir md0 var
# create two folder md0 for /dev/sdc1
# And var for /dev/sdb1

mount /dev/md0 md0
# mount /dev/sdc1 in md0

mount /dev/sdb1 var
# mount /dev/sdb1 in var


# Before this command check very well before, because it has attribute -delete, it deletes files in the destination(md0) that are not found in the source(var/)
# check "Copy entire file system hierarchy from one drive to another" and "rsync how to do a checksum on rsync" links

rsync -axcHAWXS -delete --numeric-ids --info=progress2 var/ md0/

# Copy data from old to new partition
# I added 2 attributes here `c` and `-delete`
# c: for checksum
# -delete: to delete files in new disk/partition that not exist in source or old disk/partition

# NOTE IF DATA IS LARGE AND YOU WANT TO SLEEP OR SOMETHING USE nohup & exit TO RUN IN BACKGROUND, AND CHECK "nohup.out" FOR CHANGES, LIKE "tail -f nohup.out" OR "htop" SEARCH FOR "rsync"
nohup rsync -axcHAWXS -delete --numeric-ids --info=progress2 var/ md0/ & exit
```

**umount partitions**
we need to umount partitions

```
umount /dev/sdb1
umount /dev/md0
```

**Add old disk/partition to RAID 1**
We need to add the old disk/partition(`/dev/sdb1`) to RAID 1(`md0`), check status with `cat /proc/mdstat` or `mdadm --detail /dev/md0`

```
sudo mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --raid-devices=2 --add /dev/sdb1
# check progress with cat /proc/mdstat
# or sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0 
# For progress 
# Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
#    0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
#    1       8       17        1      spare rebuilding   /dev/sdb1
# Check "spare rebuilding" and "Rebuild Status"
```

**Mount RAID 1(`md0`) to `/var`**
We need to do some changes to `mdadm.conf` and we need `/var` folder

```
mount /dev/md0 /var
# mounting md0 to /var, check that exist /var forlder if not, create it with mkdir /var
```

**Add RAID 1 to `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`**
We need to add the new array RAID 1(`md0`) to `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`

```
mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
# Add output of  mdadm --detail --scan
# To /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
# You can edit it manually

update-initramfs -u
# To take effect the new configuration
```

**Add RAID 1 to `/etc/fstab` to mount at start of server**
We need to add `/dev/md0` to `/etc/fstab`, we want to mount it at start of the server, first we need the `UUID`, we can use `lsblk -f` or `blkid`

```
blkid
# get /dev/md0 UUID

nano /etc/fstab
# At the end add this with you UUID
# UUID=0518f527-4019-4a51-b321-7ad266e1df64  /var  ext4  defaults  0  2
# Change the UUID with your UUID
# check errors with 
# findmnt --verify
```

**Restart server and check results**

```
reboot now
```

**Links that will help you:**

[How to Create a New Ext4 File System (Partition) in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/create-new-ext4-file-system-partition-in-linux/)
[Copy entire file system hierarchy from one drive to another](https://superuser.com/a/1185401/614284)
[rsync how to do a checksum on rsync](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19540611/5287072)
[Remove mdadm raid1 without loosing data](https://askubuntu.com/a/684462/541090)
[How to Create Partitions in Linux](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-create-partition#ftoc-heading-7)
[Setting up RAID 1 on 14.04 with an existing drive](https://askubuntu.com/a/526785/541090)
[Using mdadm --examine to write mdadm.conf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23879/using-mdadm-examine-to-write-mdadm-conf)
[My RAID 1 always renames itself to /dev/md127 after rebooting | DEBIAN 10](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/544841/my-raid-1-always-renames-itself-to-dev-md127-after-rebooting-debian-10)
[Mount drive in linux and set auto-mount at boot](https://confluence.jaytaala.com/display/TKB/Mount+drive+in+linux+and+set+auto-mount+at+boot)